# Multi model attribute from single jsp form spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I created a *single jsp* form which wants to send data to *two table*. It means I created two model class, so the form should refer those two model class. I tried, but failed. How to get **two** modelAttribute from **one jsp page** and assign to **one controller**. Thanks in advance.

```
`@Entity
@Table(name = "survey")
public class Survey {
    // all anotations and getters and setters are omitted
    private int surveyId;
    private String surveyName;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "preferred")
public class Survey {
    // all anotations and getters and setters are omitted
    private int preferredId;
    private String preferredClass;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="surveyId")
    private Survey survey;
}
```

**jsp form**

```
<spring:url value="/survey/save" var="saveURL"></spring:url>
<form:form action="${saveURL}" method="POST" modelAttribute="surveyForm">

    //Survey model class
    <form:hidden path="surveyId" /> 
    <form:input path="surveyName" />

    //preferredClass model class
    <form:input path="preferredClass">      

    <button type="submit" >Submit</button>  

</form:form>
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
//here I need to get ModelAttribuete of Survey and preferredClass
public ModelAndView saveSurvey( @ModelAttribute("surveyForm") Survey survey ,.........// how to get attributes of preferredClass  ) {

    surveyService.saveOrUpdate(survey); 
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/survey/list");
}`
```

Comment: Either create two forms on front end, or, create a composite object and use it on your form.

Comment: Im new to spring, could you please give me a example?

Comment: Why two same Survey objects??

Comment: No I need preferredClass object

Answer (score 1):

I realized your question in this way:
you need one api in your controller to return two type of data.

IActionResult.java

```
public interface IActionResult<T> {
}
```

ActionResultBase.java

```
public abstract class ActionResultBase<T> implements 

    IActionResult<T>,Serializable {
    }
```

ActionResult.java

```
public class ActionResult<T> extends ActionResultBase<T> {
}
```

and chang your entity to

```
public class Survey1 implements Serializable,IActionResult<Survey1> 

 public class Survey2 implements Serializable,IActionResult<Survey2>
```

and in your controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 //here I need to get ModelAttribuete of Survey and preferredClass
 public ResponseEntity<IActionResult> saveSurvey( @ModelAttribute("surveyForm") Survey survey)
    {
       if(your desired condition 1){
           //do your Business
           return new ResponseEntity<IActionResult>(survay1, HttpStatus.OK(any things you like);
           }

        if(your desired condition 2){                
           //do your Business    
           return new ResponseEntity<IActionResult>(survay2, tpStatus.OK(any things you like);
            }

}
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.